# vaadin getURL return HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using LoginForm component for authentication on our website. Once installed SSL on the IIS and opening the website, I get a browser warning that the component is referenced a non secured URL.

The problem of the following code of LoginForm component:

```
String appUri = getApplication().getURL().toString() + getWindow().getName() + "/";
```

It return HTTP instead of HTTPS

How I can fix that ?

Comment: Looks like iis is dringend the ssl termination, so your tomcat knows nothing about https. You will have to modify the returned URL yourself

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Appuri is a string,  should not be a problem to replace http with https

Comment: I cannot change that since I'm using a framework component and that code it's inside that component

Comment: Can you please describe your setup /environment? It's hard to guess when you give no details

Comment: Vaadin version 6? For 7 or 8 Page.getCurrent().getLocation()

Comment: vaadin version 6. What I did I recreated my LogonForm component and ovverided the appUri variable